# Is there a CS term to categorize react-hook-ish pattern

Tags: language-agnostic, react-hooks, terminology

I’m searching for a term to describe react hook. I’m not sure is it a design pattern? If it is, then which existing pattern should it be assigned to? Or none because it’s sth brand new?

Or is it *not* a design pattern? Then I’m really in lack of vocabulary  to describe what it is. How would you describe react hook to a friend programmer who doesn’t speak JavaScript and know nothing about react?

Background: Big fan of react hook here. For curiosity reason, I want to dig deeper about the idea of hooks, see beyond, but don’t know what to input to google besides “react hook”, so I need some terms.

Comment: I thought the term was just called "hooks." :-D https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking

Comment: @adamz4008 wow I didn’t know that “hook” is actually a term. Thanks